.NET: Is there an existing dependency-injection method for setting up cookies for an HttpClient/HttpClientFactory?
I have lots of HttpClient dependency-injected services. I use an HttpClientFactory to get these.
There are variations, but in a simple case:
// Configure a named and configured HTTP client called "MyHttpClient"
var httpClientBuilder = services.AddHttpClient("MyHttpClient", (sp, client) => /* configure the client */);

...

// Set up the DI service with a factory that gets the named "MyHttpClient"
services.AddTransient<ICustomService>(
    s => 
        new CustomService(
            s.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("MyHttpClient")));

I have a service that responds with Set-Cookie headers (in this case AWSALB load balancing indicators from AWS, but this question is for any cookies) - I want the HttpClient to respond with these cookies.
I can take that httpClientBuilder and use it to create a custom handler that sets up a CookieContainer to do this, but it feels like re-inventing the wheel.
Is there an existing solution for this? Something like:
services.AddHttpClient(...)
    .AddCookieHandler(); // Automatically set up `CookieContainer` for all requests


We can use ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler to implement this feature, here is the sample code.
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyHttpClient", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://yoursite.com");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
})
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
    {
        handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    }
    handler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();  
    return handler;
});


Yes, I mentioned this in the question, but it feels like reinventing the wheel - this sample is a start, but now you need to manage that CookieContainer too (is it global, per user, are there cookies it should ignore, etc) and this is very boilerplate stuff. It seems weird there's no easier/best practice way to do this?

Also, why did you edit the tag to asp.net-core? I'm testing a DI service in a console app and calling a 3rd party on AWS, ASP has nothing to do with it.

Hi @Keith， Because your question mentioned cookies, I thought you were using web-related technologies, so I added the asp.net-core tag. At the same time, I also think that the issues you are concerned about are also applicable to asp.net-core related areas.
